# SQL Server full text searching contains only matching whole word

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently using

```
select * 
from movies 
where contains(Name, @SearchText)
```

but it won't work for searches like `jaw`

I'm also converting any spaces into ANDs in the stored procedure to support multiple words:

```
set @SearchText = REPLACE(@SearchText, ' ', ' and ')
```

which might be causing it as well

**Movies** table:

```
ID  Name
---------------------
1   Jaws
2   Jaws 2: The revenge
3   Jaws 3-D
4   Rocky 5000
```

I have this logic in a stored procedure in which the `@SearchText` is optional and defaults to null. This also throws an error:

> Null or empty full-text predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in code instead of in sql and by using the correct contains syntax

This issue I believe was due to not wrapping double quotes around each word and adding a wildcard character.

```
private static string PrepareSearchText(string searchText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        return "\"*\"";

    searchText = searchText.Trim();

    string rv = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in searchText.Split(' '))
        rv += $"\"{item}*\" and ";

    return rv.Remove(rv.Length - 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer after comment

```
CREATE TABLE #movies(
ID int,[Name] varchar(100))

INSERT #movies (ID,[Name])
VALUES (1,'Jaws'),
        (2,'Jaws 2: The revenge'),
        (3,'Jaws 3-D'),
        (4,'Rocky 5000')

DECLARE @SearchText nvarchar(100) = 'jaws revenge ';

--Remove spaces at the beginning and end
SET @SearchText = RTRIM(LTRIM(@SearchText));
--Replace spaces to build search string
SET @SearchText = REPLACE(@SearchText,' ','%'' AND [Name] LIKE ''%')
--Finish building sql query
SET @SearchText = 'SELECT * FROM #movies WHERE [Name] LIKE''%' + @SearchText + '%'''
--Execute query
EXEC sp_executesql @SearchText

DROP TABLE #movies
```

Comment: I need full text for other search cases of 'jaws revenge', 'revenge jaws', etc. and the like clause won't handle those

Comment: @user3953989 I modified my answer. Maybe that could be your solution inside of the stored procedure.